# How to differentiate Bitmojis gender?

Tags: python, image-classification, training, pytorch, image-recognition

I have seen this Project [Larry-zx's Githubproject](https://github.com/Larry-zx/bitmoji-faces-gender-recognition)

It is used to create a .pth file which can differenciate between a bitmojis gender.

Now I have created that .pth file but no idea how to use it, please help as I want a simple print Male or Female for an image I input

Answer (score 1):

This depends a bit on how the `.pth` file is created. Given that you're only saving the state dict you can create an instance of the corresponding model type (i.e. convnext, mobilenet, resnet etc., stored in the `convnext.py` and `networks.py` files in the `model` directory and load the weights using the `load_state_dict` method (see also [the pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-load-state-dict-recommended)). If the entire model is saved you can simply use `torch.load` to load the full model.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I have made the default convnext model. I assume I need to use the weights convnext.py but it looks like the state dictionary that I am trying to load contains keys that are not present in the model's state dictionary